# Windows store device app without UI on Windows 10

Tags: windows, uwp, device

I need to create a [windows store device app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devapps/)(UWP) for my device, it's only function is show a toast notification when the device pluged in. And the requirement is when user click the shortcut, it should not show it's splash and UI, it can show the toast notification or open a web page when click the shortcut. Is that feasible? Any other better solution are appreciate.